# Higher order Partial derivatives and chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Question: 
Let $f$ be a real valued function in $C^{(2)}(R^{2})$. Let $c$ be a positive constant. Define $y_{1}=g_{1}=x_{1}+cx_{2}$ and $y_{2}=g_{2}=x_{1}-cx_{2}$. Let $g=(g_{1},g_{2})$ and $h=f\circ g$. Find $D_{22}f(x)-c^{2}D_{11}f(x)$ in terms of the derivatives of $h$.

My book is "Introduction to mathematical analysis" by Steven A.Douglass and question is from chapter 8 (Differential Calculus in $R^{n}$), number $19$.

Notation: For any differentiable real valued function $f(x_{1},...,x_{n}):U\subseteq R^{n}\rightarrow R$ and $c \in U$, we denote $D_{i}f(c)=\partial f/\partial x_{i}$ and $D_{ij}f(c)=\partial^{2}f/\partial x_{i}\partial x_{j}$ evaluated at $c$.

I don't understand the notation $D_{22}f(x)-c^{2}D_{11}f(x)$. Does $D_{22}f(x)$ imply $\partial^{2}f/\partial x_{2}^{2}$ or $\partial^{2}f/\partial y_{2}^{2}$ ?